# UTF-8 tuple storage using lowest common technological denominator, append-only

Tags: database, language-agnostic, storage, csv

**EDIT: Note that due to the way hard drives actually write data, none of the schemes in this list work reliably. Do not use them. Just use a database. SQLite is a good simple one.**

What's the most low-tech but reliable way of storing tuples of UTF-8 strings on disk? Storage should be append-only for reliability.

As part of a document storage system I'm experimenting with I have to store UTF-8 tuple data on disk. Obviously, for a full-blown implementation, I want to use something like Amazon S3, Project Voldemort, or CouchDB.

However, at the moment, I'm experimenting and haven't even firmly settled on a programming language yet. I have been using CSV, but CSV tend to become brittle when you try to store outlandish unicode and unexpected whitespace (eg vertical tabs).

I could use XML or JSON for storage, but they don't play nice with append-only files. My best guess so far is a rather idiosyncratic format where each string is preceded by a 4-byte signed integer indicating the number of bytes it contains, and an integer value of -1 indicates that this tuple is complete - the equivalent of a CSV newline. The main source of headaches there is having to decide on the endianness of the integer on disk.

*Edit: actually, this won't work. If the program exits while writing a string, the data becomes irrevocably misaligned. Some sort of out-of-band signalling is needed to ensure alignment can be regained after an aborted tuple.*

*Edit 2: Turns out that guaranteeing atomicity when appending to text files is possible, but the parser is quite non-trivial. Writing said parser now.*

*Edit 3: You can view the end result at http://github.com/MetalBeetle/Fruitbat/tree/master/src/com/metalbeetle/fruitbat/atrio/ .*

Comment: Very interesting question. I don't have an answer, but i'm thinking of something like Git's model of object storage. What lengths are these strings typically, and can they contain null bytes?

Comment: @Chris They are likely to be fairly short for the most part, and they may contain null. The system is indeed fairly git-esque in many ways, but aimed at storing paperwork, not code.

Comment: Also, is the UTF-8 data mostly 7-bit ASCII-compatible? That is, are most of the codepoints in the range 0-127?

Comment: @Chris: They are, but all codepoints up to the astral planes should be supported, even if space-inefficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend tab delimiting each field and carriage-return delimiting each record.

Within each string, Replace all characters that would affect the field and record interpretation and rendering. This would include control characters (U+0000–U+001F, U+007F–U+009F), non-graphical line and paragraph separators (U+2028, U=2029), directional control characters (U+202A–U+202E), and the byte order mark (U+FEFF).

They should be replaced with escape sequences of constant length. The escape sequences should begin with a rare (for your application) character. The escape character itself should also be escaped.

This would allow you to append new records easily. It has the additional advantage of being able to load the file for visual inspection and modification into any spreadsheet or word processing program, which could be useful for debugging purposes.

This would also be easy to code, since the file will be a valid UTF-8 document, so standard text reading and writing routines may be used. This also allows you to convert easily to UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE if desired, without complications.

Example:

```
U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION becomes ~TB
U+000A LINE FEED            becomes ~LF
U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN      becomes ~CR
U+007E TILDE                becomes ~~~
etc.
```

There are a couple of reasons why tabs would be better than commas as field delimiters. Commas appear more commonly within normal text strings (such as English text), and would have to be replaced more frequently. And spreadsheet programs (such as Microsoft Excel) tend to handle tab-delimited files much more naturally.

Comment: Could probably use url-encoding then, as that is already standard.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström - URL encoding also converts spaces and (I’m guessing) quotes, which I would prefer to keep intact, but since it’s likely to be available in the language libraries, using that turns this whole project into just plugging a few pieces together, so that’s a pretty good idea.

Comment: Yes, i agree, it wouldn't have to be full url encoding though, just for the problematic bytes. Otherwise the length of mostly non-ASCII-compatible strings would double or triple.

Comment: Or one could of course just use the good old escape sequences \\ \r \t \n \x00

Answer (score 1):

Mostly thinking out loud here...

Really low tech would be to use (for example) null bytes as separators, and just "quote" all null bytes appearing in the output with an additional null.

Perhaps one could use [SCSU](http://unicode.org/reports/tr6/) along with that.

Or it might be worth to look at the [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#file-format) format, and maybe ape it, if not using it:

> A gzip file consists of a series of "members" (compressed data sets).

[...]

> The members simply appear one after another in the file, with no additional information before, between, or after them.

Each of these members can have an optional "filename", comment, or the like, and i believe you can just keep appending members.

Or you could use [bencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode), used in torrent-files. Or [BSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON).

See also [Wikipedia's Comparison of data serialization formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).

Otherwise i think your idea of preceding each string with its length is probably the simplest one.